# xslt 2.0 format currentdate

Tags: xml, datetime, xslt, xsd, xslt-2.0

**xslt 2.0**

I have xsd:dateTime field to which I have to assign current datetime formatted as

```
[D01]-[M01]-[Y0001] [h01]:[m01]:[s01] and using the below function

format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), '[D01]-[M01]-[Y0001] [h01]:[m01]:[s01]')
```

I am able to assign the above output to a xsd:string element and not to xsd:datetime element. I even tried of typecasting the same as `xsd:dateTime(format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), '[D01]-[M01]-[Y0001] [h01]:[m01]:[s01]'))` but nothing works.. Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? If you want to manipulate the value as a date/time object, then don't format it. Once you have formatted it, it's just a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format for the `xs:dateTime` data type is defined as `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` plus some timezone information. The `format-dateTime` function returns a string in the format you specify but not a value of type `xs:dateTime`. So what you want to do there is not possible, you can bind the result of `current-dateTime()` to a variable of type `xs:dateTime`, but certainly not the result of your `format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), '[D01]-[M01]-[Y0001] [h01]:[m01]:[s01]')` expression, as that is a string in a format not representing an `xs:dateTime` value.